# Laravel Repositories Relationhips

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, repository

I have a simple relationship between users and posts(User model and Post model) and i am using  Repositories.

```
<?php namespace St0iK\Storage\Post;

use Post;

class EloquentPostRepository implements PostRepository {

  protected $errors;

  public function all()
  {
    return Post::all();
  }

  public function find($id)
  {
    return Post::find($id);
  }

  public function create($input)
  { 
      return Post::create($input);
  }


}
```

In my controller i have:

```
  public function store()
  {
    // Get input from the form
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['user_id'] =   (int)Auth::user()->id;
    $p =  $this->post->create( Input::all() );

    if( $p->errors()->isEmpty() )
    {
      return Redirect::route('home')->with('flash', 'The new post has been created');
    }

    return Redirect::route('upload.create')->withInput()->withErrors($p->errors());
  }
```

But the 'post' is not inserted in the database. I get validation errors(i am using Ardent) that all my fields are missing!
But if i try something like that in my controller:

```
$user = User::find( (int)Auth::user()->id);
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

it works just fine.

How can i implement this to my Post Repository so i can insert a new Post with re related user and pass the user_id?

Comment: Did you set your $fillable = [/*fields here*/]; in your Post model?

Comment: yeap protected $fillable = array('user_id','category_id','title','slug','description','active','pic_url','tags');

Comment: I used public static function xxx() in my repository, not sure if that makes a difference? I think I gave up on that after encountering similar issue. Looking over my code it appears that I'm not using the repositories after all. Sorry to not have been of help.

Comment: First off, don't use `User::find(Auth::user()->id)`, all you need is `Auth::user()`. Don't user `Auth::user()->id`, all you need is `Auth::id()` - a bit less queries run. Now, you use `Input::all()` but assign some data to `$input`.. Clean it up and show the code that works for you (not just part)